# How to retain existing secret_version for terraform when doing import

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-secrets-manager

I'm trying to refactor my terraform code from using indexes to for_each.

I'm using terraform 1.0.1

I faced this problem where by even after I import my resources, `terraform plan` still returns me result saying that i need to recreate the resources.

Is there anything i can do to kind make it stay and use the existing setup ?

sample outputs:

```
  # module.cluster.module.secrets.random_password.passwords["demo1"] must be replaced
-/+ resource "random_password" "passwords" {
      ~ id               = "none" -> (known after apply)
      + length           = 20 # forces replacement
      + lower            = true # forces replacement
      + min_lower        = 0 # forces replacement
      + min_numeric      = 0 # forces replacement
      + min_special      = 0 # forces replacement
      + min_upper        = 0 # forces replacement
      + number           = true # forces replacement
      + override_special = "_%@" # forces replacement
      ~ result           = (sensitive value)
      + special          = true # forces replacement
      + upper            = true # forces replacement
    }


  # module.cluster.module.secrets.aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.secret_version["demo1"] must be replaced
-/+ resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret_version" "secret_version" {
      ~ arn            = "arn:aws:secretsmanager:ap-southeast-1:xxx:secret:demo1-xxxx" -> (known after apply)
      ~ id             = "arn:aws:secretsmanager:ap-southeast-1:xxx:secret:demo1-xxxx|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" -> (known after apply)
      # Warning: this attribute value will be marked as sensitive and will not
      # display in UI output after applying this change.
      ~ secret_string  = (sensitive value) # forces replacement
      ~ version_id     = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" -> (known after apply)
        # (2 unchanged attributes hidden)
    }
```

implementation:
Codes that are commented are previous implementation using indexes.

```
resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret" "secret" {
//  count = length(var.secrets)
//  name = var.secrets[count.index].secret_name

  for_each = { for secret in var.secrets : secret.secret_name => secret}
  name = each.value.secret_name

}

resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret_version" "secret_version" {
//  count = length(var.secrets)
//  secret_id = aws_secretsmanager_secret.secret[count.index].id
//  secret_string = jsonencode({
//    username = var.secrets[count.index].username
//    password = var.generate_password ? random_password.passwords[count.index].result : var.secrets[count.index].password
//  })
//  version_stages = ["AWSCURRENT"]

  for_each = { for secret in var.secrets : secret.secret_name => secret}
  secret_id = aws_secretsmanager_secret.secret[each.value.secret_name].id
  secret_string = jsonencode({
    username = each.value.username
    password = var.generate_password ? random_password.passwords[each.value.secret_name].result : var.secrets[each.value.secret_name].password
  })
  version_stages = ["AWSCURRENT"]
}

resource "random_password" "passwords" {
//  count = var.generate_password ? length(var.secrets) : 0
//  length = 20
//  special = true
//  override_special = "_%@"

  for_each = {
    for secret in var.secrets : secret.secret_name => secret
    if var.generate_password
  }
  length = 20
  special = true
  override_special = "_%@"
}
```

Comment: Those are being re-created because Terraform will not store the sensitive secrets in its state, and therefore the provider cannot ensure idempotence. Instead of removing them from the state and importing them afterward, you should have moved the state address after changing your config. Is that still an option, or are you past that point now?

Comment: yeah i did a move. and it is working as expected. thanks

Comment: @MattSchuchard as per my current test even terraform 1.3.5 is storing secret version secretstring in the statefile. Also I have another problem while trying to import a secret version created using terraform 0.11.15 to terraform 1.3.5 it thinks the secrets version has to be recreated, it happens only for json values and not for just a string value.